# I was wondering how i would be able to a local host website that i am developing from my windows website on my iphone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, localhost

I have tried doing this by entering the IPv4 Address that I got from my windows machine from the command prompt under "wireless LAN adapter wi-fi" on my mobile phone (iPhone) but this never works. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

ngrok exposes your local servers to public internet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure your windows and iphone are under the same WLAN. Then expose the specific firewall port you use or stop the firewall temporarily. Now you can access website winip:port using your iphone.